# How to Access Data from Webhook in Odoo if first JSON parameter is not "params"?

Tags: python-requests, odoo, webhooks, json-rpc

I am trying to receive webhooks from third party software into Odoo. I can receive the request, but the data is blank.

This is the default JSON from the webhook:

```
    {
    "event": "{{{PARTICLE_EVENT_NAME}}}",
    "data": "{{{PARTICLE_EVENT_VALUE}}}",
    "coreid": "{{{PARTICLE_DEVICE_ID}}}",
    "published_at": "{{{PARTICLE_PUBLISHED_AT}}}"
    }
```

However, with the Odoo code below, if I "print(kw)" with _logger it is a blank Dict.

```
from odoo import http
import json
import datetime
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class EquipmentTrackerApi(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/api/v1/tracker_data', auth='public', csrf=False, type='json', methods=['POST'])
    def _create_tracker_data(self, **kw):
        _request = kw
        _logger.info(kw)
```

In my testing, if I change the JSON to the following then I can read the data and finish my operation. However the issue is I can't actually change this in production. So how do I access the JSON data if I can't make the below change?

```
{
  "params": {
    "event": "{{{PARTICLE_EVENT_NAME}}}",
    "data": "{{{PARTICLE_EVENT_VALUE}}}",
    "coreid": "{{{PARTICLE_DEVICE_ID}}}",
    "published_at": "{{{PARTICLE_PUBLISHED_AT}}}"
  }
}
```

I've heard about this being an issue within Odoo and how it processes requests, but can't see any solutions out there. Any ideas how to get around this in Odoo? I have the same issue in v12 & v13.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
from odoo import http

import json, logging, request


_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class EquipmentTrackerApi(http.Controller):

@http.route('/api/v1/tracker_data', auth='public', csrf=False, type='json', methods=['POST'])
    def _create_tracker_data(self, **kw):
        # data = json.loads(request.httprequest.args)
        data = json.loads(request.httprequest.data)            
        _request = data
        _logger.info(data)
```